# I am having a problem with Firebase Auth-UI user metadata

Tags: firebase

I am using Firebase Auth UI to register and store users in my app.

When the user is new in the app, I need to register some things, so I need to know when a user is new or not.

According to the documentation I am using the right way to check new users:
[Auth-UI Metadata](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/auth/README.md#user-metadata)

The way I check to know wheter a user is new or not is comparing the metadata, user creation timestamp and Last Signed Timestamp and it worked perfect.

```
if (metadata.getCreationTimestamp() == metadata.getLastSignInTimestamp()){
  //do some new user stuff
}else{
 //log in old user
}
```

This code is not working right now, because they might have changed something.

The last time I am sure this code worked is the 30th of January.

There is a little difference in miliseconds between the creation timestamp and the sign in timestamp when the user is new:

Creation timestamp: 1549462011000 Last Sign in Timestamp: 1549462011028

I've tried in two different Firebase projects and the problem is the same.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I experienced the same problem with my app.
The two timestamps have now few milliseconds difference.
A way to fix it is to check the two timestamps are close enough ( 3 seconds in the code below)

```
val signUpInterval = 3000L 
val isNewUser = Math.abs(metadata.creationTimestamp - metadata.lastSignInTimestamp) < signUpInterval
```

Comment: Yes, thank you it works. But, I guess they will have to fix this bug.